# Creating scene component in c++ actor class

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a base c++ character class, that is inherited by a blueprint. The c++ class creates a capsule component which it later uses for testing overlaps. The inherited blueprint class is where the capsule size, radius and positions are being configured.

```
Zone = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCapsuleComponent>( TEXT( "Zone" ) );
Zone->SetupAttachment( GetMesh( ) );
```

The problem I am facing is that I need the capsule to be attached to an animation socket. For some reason it is not allowed, the editor says "*Cannot change socket on inherited components*".

Is there a preferred/recommended way of doing things like this? It seems fairly basic setup so I can't imagine it being impossible. So far I tried several methods, but all feels somewhat wrong:

1. Set the attachment in c++ only - it's rather hard considering the mesh+animation are being setup in the blueprint, so I have to jump through a lot of hoops to do it - exposing tons of variables etc, I really didn't like it.
2. Use `AttachComponentToComponent` in the blueprint construction script. This one almost works, but the editor often "bugs" (after several re-compilations of the c++ code) - the capsule becomes frozen in place and cannot be moved.
3. Change the setup flow a bit - the c++ class only declare the variable, but leave it to the blueprint to set it up. Then in the blueprint I create a capsule component and call `Set Zone = TheCapsule`. Again, almost works, and it allows more freedom of where/how the component is being created - but the blueprint code often becomes invalid after recompiling the c++ code. The box with the "Set Zone" method in the construction script becomes red and I have to recreate it.

So is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!